# Automatic edit a config file with password after deployment from github to azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, umbraco

I have a asp.net web application on Azure, with continous integration from GitHub. Works good, and I have managed to move most of the passwords and connectionstrings off the source and into application settings. However there is one file I cannot manage to solve how to provide a connectionstring without having it in source. The file FileSystemProviders.config looks like:

```
 <Provider alias="media" type="Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureBlobFileSystem, Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure">
   <Parameters>
     <add key="connectionString" value="**SECRET1**"/>
```

Is there anyway to make a script running after each deployment that replaces **SECRET1** with my connectionstring automatically? Or any other way around?

Comment: You can Encrypt your configuration file so that no one can able to see your **SECRET1** value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, posting it in case anyone wondering about the same. The Kudu service has some [post deployment action hooks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks). So after creating a new directory in "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\" named "PostDeploymentActions", I put the two files into the directory, and the script copies the connectionstrings into right place.

1. CopyFiles.bat

   ```
   copy D:\home\site\deployments\tools\PostDeploymentActions\HiddenFileSystemProviders.config D:\home\site\wwwroot\Config\FileSystemProviders.config
   ```
2. HiddenFileSystemProviders.config is my config file with my private connectionstring.

The scripts runs after each deployment from GitHub to Azure.